# Does Asp.NET Core have a way to declare services scoped to the duration of a Blazor circuit/session?

Tags: asp.net-core, service, scope, blazor

I guess I could make AddSingleton work for this if I add my own layer upon it that manually keeps data in memory mapped to the current session/circuit/whatever ID (along with manual GC), but I feel like this sorta defeats the point of DI. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided much context here's how to get a scoped service container from the top level service provider that will create scoped and Transient services within the new container.  This is how `OwningComponentBase` does it (it lives for the lifetime of the component and gets correctly disposed when the component is destroyed):

```
   [Inject] IServiceScopeFactory ScopeFactory { get; set; } = default!;


    protected IServiceProvider ScopedServices
    {
        get
        {
            if (ScopeFactory == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Services cannot be accessed before the component is initialized.");

            if (this.IsDisposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException($"{this.GetType().Name}");

            _scope ??= ScopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
            return _scope.Value.ServiceProvider;
        }
    }

public TService GetService<TService>()
            => ScopedServices.GetRequiredService<TService>();
```

You do need to be careful about which `instance` of scoped services you want to use/ are using.

You can also build your own service provider:

```cs
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        // Adds the application services to the collection
         ......
        // Creates a Service Provider from the Services collection
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Get a service
        var service = provider.GetService<TService>();

        // Dispose of the provider
        provider.Dispose();
        provider = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to use the 'Session' to initialize a service scoped to your session. It is accessible in your controller methods.

Something like this

```
Session["MyService"] = new MyService();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to pertain to SignalR (Blazor) circuits (which I guess are not to be confused with sessions).

Comment: Not sure I understand. Did you want a separate SignalR instance per session which would seem to defeat the point of signal R?

Comment: I think I meant the contiguous SignalR circuit as a session by the general definition of the concept of a session. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the nature of a circuit?